# spring MVC two forms with one controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Here is the Jsp file. I want a controller that handles both the forms in just one page. is there a way to handle this form? I create a controller but it cannot bind the forms.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"   %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to Spring Web MVC project</title>
</head>

<body>
   <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="logindetails" name ="LoginForm" autocomplete="off" >

            Dept_Code :

          <form:input path="departmentcode"/>


          Dept_name
          <form:input path="departmentname" placeholder="name" />



  <button type="submit" >Save</button>



   </form:form><br/>

   <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="emp_details" name = "emp_Form" autocomplete="off" >

            Emp_Code :

          <form:input path="emp_code"/>


          Emp_Coded
          <form:input path="Emp_coded" placeholder="coded" />

          DDO_Desc
          <form:input path="ddo_desc" placeholder="DDO_DESC" />



  <button type="submit" >Save</button>



   </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my controller Class if you need in case. but I only bind for one form.

```
@Controller
public class DepartmentController {
@Autowired
Deptservices deptservices;

 @RequestMapping(value="index", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView insert(@ModelAttribute("logindetails") Department insert)
{
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("index");
    return mav;
}

 @RequestMapping(value="index", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView insertPost(@ModelAttribute("logindetails") Department insert)
{
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("index");
    deptservices.insert(insert);
    return mav;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have bind the model with name `logindetails`.

So, change `modelAttribute="emp_details"` to `modelAttribute="logindetails"` in second form.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But, it doesn't work that way. I hope you understand my question. both the form should insert in different tables namely, dept and emp respectively. So it should be a one to many mapping. the save button of the first form will be disabled when you insert an existing primary key. but you can save as many as you like in the second form.

Comment: Why making it complex. What is the problem having 2 separate controllers methods for those 2 different operations?

Comment: To be frank im new to spring mvc. Is there an easy way to complete my need?

Comment: You can create 2 beans Employee and Department where Department contains List<Employee> collection. Now write 2 Controller methods, one to save only Department details and second to add a new Employee to an existing Department. In the second form pass departmentCode to which the Employee has to be associated.

Comment: Thank you @  sivaprasadreddy.k

Answer (score 0):

take a view model like

```
EmployeeViewMOdel{
logindetails
emp_details
}

model.addAttribute("EmployeeViewMOdelObj",EmployeeViewMOdel);
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="*EmployeeViewMOdelObj*" name ="LoginForm" autocomplete="off" >


<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="EmployeeViewMOdelObj" name = "emp_Form" autocomplete="off" >
```

bind this object to both the forms and then single controller may handle your request.

Comment: After a lot of research. I can get what i want. Thanks a lot.